# Checking if a user is logged in clientside

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, session-cookies, passport-local

I am using `node.js` and with `passport.js` to make a local authentication, but I wanted to know how would I know if a client is authenticated client side.

What would be the best solution of checking if a client is authenticated withing my angularjs code? Would it just check if the cookie containing the session id is active?

Comment: Check for the x-authorization cookie ? Depends on how you store your session client-side

Answer (score 2):

Passport uses middleware to manage persistent user sessions on the server side and methods for parsing and securing the users request information:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

If you're using the built-in localstrategy of Passport, your users information (username/password) would only be transmitted during initial POST.  On success, the users information can be persisted in the session on the server for future validation.  In my Backbone applications I have used JSON Web Tokens [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) to store (not the user information, but just a session identifier) only the session ID on the client.  JWT allows you to define a session secret to encrypt an X-auth cookie and store this cookie on the client.  Then on the client-side you can attach a function to the ajaxSend event to transmit the cookie with all subsequent requests:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request) {
    var token = readCookie('token');
    if (token) {
        request.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
});
```

Session information can be serialized/deserialized into and out of the session to obtain the user identifier from the auth token that contains the session id.  This is in my opinion the best approach since it limits the amount of data stored on the client and provides better security than storing any user information. Here is a [fantastic explanation and example](https://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/06/26/build-user-authentication-with-node-js-express-passport-and-orchestrate/) of the local passport strategy and how it can be used to support sessions in client side applications.

Here's an example of how you might implement server side validation of the client cookie in Express:

```
//Set a session secret
var secrets = { sessionSecret: process.env.secret || 'my secret string'};

//Require express-jwt and set a secret for the cookie
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var validateJwt = expressJwt({ secret: secrets.sessionSecret });

//Returns a jwt token signed by the app secret
var signToken = function(id) {
    return jwt.sign({
        id: id
    }, secrets.sessionSecret, {
        expiresInMinutes: 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    });
};

//Set token cookie directly
var setTokenCookie = function(req, res) {
    if (!req.user) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Error during user validation'
        });
    }
    var token = signToken(req.user.id, req.user.role);
    res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(token));
};

//Check to see if user is authenticated (call this when a route is requested)
var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
    if (req.body && req.body.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.body.access_token;
    }
    // Validate jwt token
    return validateJwt(req, res, next);
};
```

Comment: Can you further explain what is the 'secret' value? I didn't quite understand it.

In addition, when should i check if the target is authorized? is there a specific wanted location? And how would i check serverside if the cookie is correct?

Comment: JWT uses a set of hash algorithms to encode a message by using a string created by you, the developer.  Here is a great introduction to JWT: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: By including the jwt module (express-jwt if you're using Express) in your node app, you sign and validate the client token to ensure it is secured and only you have the 'secret' that decodes it and ensure it has not been tampered with (respectively).  In terms of checking client validation, this is typically done as a callback in your route definition. 

app.get('/myRouteDef', auth.isAuthenticated, myController.myMethod);

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how authentication of the cookie could be implemented using node.js Express

Comment: There are quite a few bugs in the above example, but the idea is solid